# Retain focus on a pop up window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button on a “home page” that opens a pop up which contains several onward links.

When someone clicks on one of the onward links, the linked page opens in a new, separate window, leaving “home page” still open, and the pop up “blurs” (I think that is the correct word to mean the pop up does not close, but disappears behind “home page”).

I would like the pop up to remain in “focus” (on top of “home page”) until a user clicks on “Close this window” that appears at the bottom of the pop up.

This is the JavaScript that generates the popup:

```
function OpenPop() 
{
    var windowcontents = "https://example.com/link.html";
    var win = window.open(windowcontents,"remote",'toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,width=450,height=425');
    win.creator=self;
    myWindow.focus();
}
```

This is the HTML on “home page” that displays the button that opens the pop up

```
 <p class="center"><a href="javascript:OpenPop();">
                  <img src="https://www.example.com/images/link.gif" alt="Links"
                    width="130" border="0" height="51"></a></p>
```

Here is the “close this window” code at the bottom of the pop up

```
<a href="javascript:self.close()"><img src="images/close.gif" alt="Click here to close this
          window" width="102" height="9"> </a>
```

Is there a way to keep the pop up in "focus"?
Thank you.

Comment: why not use an actual popover? like [bootstrap popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/)

Comment: Thank you. I have never before heard of a "popover," and am now teaching myself what it is, and how to us it at w3schools.com